# Set Html-Tabindex back to "auto"

Tags: javascript, html, tabindex

On a Page with many form-fields I wanna set specific ones to tabindex="-1". But when the user checks a checkbox the fields with tabindex="-1" should get reached by a tabular as usual.
How to do this? Tabindex="auto" & tabindex="" don't work.

My Javascript:

```
function setTabindex(checkboxChecked) {
    var tabindexValue = cbChecked ? '' /* <-- what should I enter here? */ : '-1';
    var noTabindexElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-notabindex]');

    for (var i = 0; i < noTabindexElements.length; i++) {
        noTabindexElements[i].setAttribute('tabindex', tabindexValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.tabIndex) & [HTML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex) this should work, but I haven't tested it:

```
function setTabindex(checkboxChecked) {
    var tabindexValue = cbChecked ? 0 : -1;
    var noTabindexElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-notabindex]');

    for (var i = 0; i < noTabindexElements.length; i++) {
        noTabindexElements[i].tabIndex = tabindexValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all those who are looking for something better, you can also do this:

```
input.setAttribute("tabindex", null);
```